# Using include? command to search through the string containing mix of numbers and letters

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to check if the string is a valid phone number in the format
"XXXX XXXX", where every X is an integer from 0 to 9. If its valid return TRUE, else return FALSE.

I'm not sure why `!(0..9).include?(char)` doesnt work properly.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
def phone_number(str)
  if str.length == 9 && str[4] = " "
    str[4] = ""   
    str.each_char do |char|
      if !(0..9).include?(char)
        print false
      end
    end
    return true
  end
  return false
end

print phone_number("1234 5678") # => true
puts
print phone_number("123 5678") # => false
puts
print phone_number("1234 df78") # => false
puts
print phone_number("12345678") # => false
```

Comment: Hint: just read the line you wrote out loud in English: "Does the range of **numbers** 0 to 9 include this **character**?"

Comment: To fix your code up, use the range of characters: instead of `0..9` use `?0..?9`. It’ll work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you for some reason don’t use the regular expression, it’s still possible with plain Ruby:

```
λ = ->(str) {
  str.split(' ').tap do |parts|
    break [""] unless parts.size == 2        
  end.all? do |s|
    s.length == 4 && s.delete('[0-9]').empty?
  end
}

["1234 5678", "123 5678", "1234 df78", "12345678", "1234"].map(&λ)
#⇒ [true, false, false, false, false]
```

Here we split the string by parts, check that an amount of parts is exactly 2, both have a length of 4 and consist from digits only.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using a regex to achieve what you want to do !

Here is the example code:

```
def phone_number(str)
 !!str.match(/^\d{4}\s{1}\d{4}$/)
end

print phone_number("1234 5678") # => true
puts
print phone_number("123 5678") # => false
puts
print phone_number("1234 df78") # => false
puts
print phone_number("12345678") # => false
```

Comment: `!(0..9).include?(char)` doesn't work because `char` is not a number